# Python / SQLite - How to select from all Columns and Sum multiple colums?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

I try to Code a search (select) function for my SQLite Database. At the Moment i get a Keyword from a TextCtrl (simplified for short example here) and i try to search in every column of my SQLite Database.

```
keyword = "Product_1"
```

Better would be if i could also select with Multiple Keywords (list):

```
keywords = ["Product_1", "Category_2"]
```

How do I search in all columns?

```
c.execute('SELECT * FROM Test WHERE AnyColumns=?', (keyword,))
```

Later on i need to Sum two of my columns. At the Moment I do it like this:

```
c.execute("SELECT SUM(overall_cost) FROM vm WHERE id=5")
result = cur.fetchone()[0]
c.execute("SELECT SUM(overall_price) FROM vm WHERE id=5")
result2 = cur.fetchone()[0]
```

Is it possible to do this in one step? Something like `SUM(overall_cost) and SUM(overall_price)`?

I need those two values seperate. Not summed up to one value!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes possible

```
"SELECT SUM(overall_cost) as overall_cost,SUM(overall_price) as overall_price  FROM vm WHERE id=5"
```

Comment: Working fine! Thank you! Do you also have a solution or an idea for my first problem?

Comment: Could you provide an example of that in your answer? I will accept your answer later on. And what exactly to you mean with "worst case Scenario" ?

Comment: concat doesnt work in SQlite I think, what do i Need to use in SQLite?